# PHP foreach: data as value less than a number

Tags: php, excel

I need the code to be executed only if value of `$entry[0]` is less than 10, but it doesn't work.

I know the error is here: `$data as $entry[0] < 10`

The data is an excel worksheet and `$entry[0]` is serial numbers from 1 to 100 and `$entry[1]` is text field (domain names).

```
<?php $data = wp_excel_cms_get("top100"); ?>
<?php foreach($data as $entry[0] < 10):   ?>
    <?php echo $entry[0]."&nbsp;";?>
    <a href ="<?php echo "http://". $entry[1]; ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php echo $entry[1];?></a><br />
    <hr />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `foreach` in a wrong way. First, iterate over data, then apply your logic in your sheet row data:

```
<?php $data = wp_excel_cms_get("top100"); ?>
<?php foreach($data as $entry):   ?>
    <?php if($entry[0] < 10): ?>
        <?php echo $entry[0]."&nbsp;";?><a href ="<?php echo "http://". $entry[1]; ?    >"target="_blank"><?php echo $entry[1];?></a><br />
    <?php endif; ?>
<hr />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = wp_excel_cms_get("top100");
foreach($data as $entry[0] ){
if ($entry[0] < 10){    echo $entry[0]."&nbsp;";?>
<a href ="<?php echo "http://". $entry[1]; ?    >"target="_blank"><?php echo $entry[1];?></a><br />
<?php     }     ?>
 <hr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```